# Inserting data Into MS Access, getting error "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement." VB

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007

Ok I'm new to this and I have no idea what I'm doing and I really need help

```
 Dim lnkr As New OleDbCommand(String.Format("insert into project (Student Name, Days Absent, Classes Absent, Arabic, Islamic, English, Math, Biology, Chemistry, Physic, Computer,Day Offs) values ('{0}',{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8},{9},{10},{11}", TextBox1.Text, TextBox10.Text, TextBox12.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox6.Text, TextBox3.Text, TextBox4.Text, TextBox7.Text, TextBox5.Text, TextBox9.Text, TextBox8.Text, TextBox11.Text))

    lnkr.Connection = con
    con.Open()
    lnkr.ExecuteNonQuery()

    con.Close()
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: My dear my english is not strong and i need this code in the right way i have to deliver my project tomorrow i know i'm asking alot but can you send me the correct code . :(

Comment: Student Name => [Student Name],  Days Absent => [Days Absent] etc....  Fieldnames may not contain blanks or must be enclosed by square brackets []

Comment: Thank you but i'm getting a new error "Number of query values and destination fields are not the same."

Comment: Help PLZ :(  :( :(

Answer (score 0):

You miss the placeholder {12}:

```
String.Format("insert into project ([Student Name], [Days Absent], [Classes Absent], Arabic, Islamic, English, Math, Biology, Chemistry, Physic, Computer, [Day Offs]) values ('{0}', {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {8}, {9}, {10}, {11}, {12}", TextBox1.Text, TextBox10.Text, TextBox12.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox6.Text, TextBox3.Text, TextBox4.Text, TextBox7.Text, TextBox5.Text, TextBox9.Text, TextBox8.Text, TextBox11.Text))
```

Can't tell if the position is right.